# How do I create a dynamic lower thirds i AS3 based on width of dynamic text

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe-animate

This is for big screen event and i've only got a inputfield in another program to work with.

So i've got some dynamic textfields which are for commentator / experts name and title
called name & title. i really like to mask the underlining bg shape so depending on how long the name is, the bg is matching the width + some px of my dynamic textfields. This must be in AS3

Comment: Hello and welcome to **StackOverflow**. As it happens, **StackOverflow** is not a free code delivery service. Please read this guide on asking https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then "edit" your question to add the relevant pieces: code samples you have so far and research, what have you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: You'll have to experiment & find out how many pixels are used by one letter in your textfield. Such width/height numbers depend on the font. I had to do same thing for an MP3 player where song title haa background bar of same length as text (but the pixel size was different from font size). I had to fine tune it by testing over a few mins.